# Multiprocessing Pool has 'None' output in Idle, but full text output in command prompt

Tags: python, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

When running the code below, I get 'None' output when running code from
IDLE, but I get the full text output (correct output) when running from
my command prompt. Why is this the case? Am I utilizing Pool wrong?

## testing multiprocessing

from multiprocessing import Pool

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def scrape_ticker(url):
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    for i in Soup.find_all('p'):
      print(i.get_text())
        




if __name__ == '__main__' :
    urls = ['http://www.investopedia.com/investing/biotech-stocks/', 
       'https://www.fool.com/investing/2017/06/25/5-best-biotech-stocks-of-2017-so-far.aspx',
       'http://www.marketwatch.com/story/five-reasons-you-have-to-buy-biotech-stocks-now-2017-06-20',
      'http://www.kiplinger.com/slideshow/investing/T052-S003-7-battered-biotech-stocks-to-buy/index.html',
      'http://www.investors.com/research/ibd-stock-analysis/exelexis-biotech-stock-with-497-growth-positive-trial-results-nears-buy-zone-celgene-climbs/']
    

    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    print(pool.map(scrape_ticker, urls))
```

Comment: I know IDLE uses a redirect to push sys.stdout messages to its window.  In command prompt, every message goes to the command window.  In IDLE, not every message is redirected to the IDLE window.  I've yet to find a total list of default output objects, but I've seen and had to adjust to this behavior before in IDLE.  That's not much help, hence in comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Pool.map` correctly. However, it's a known problem that `multiprocessing.Pool` will not work with interactive interpreters like IDLE. This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) underneath the example.